# How to enable code completion for wxWidgets in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, wxwidgets, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to enable code completion for **wxWidgets** in **Eclipse IDE**? It works for c++ classes, boost libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible if you configure include paths in Eclipse Indexer. From [Setup Guide](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Eclipse,_CDT_&_MingW_&_MSYS_Setup_Guide#Fixing_the_.22Unresolved_inclusion.22_Warnings_of_Eclipse_Indexer):

> In the Eclipse main menu
>
> - select "Project" -> "Properties"
> - navigate to "C/C++ General" -> "Paths and Symbols" -> (on the right)    "Includes"
>
> In the "Languages" box on the left
>
> - select GNU C++ (you might want to do the same for GNU C, though it    doesn't seem to be necessary as wxWidgets is written in C++)
> - now select "Add..." on the right side of the "Include directories"    box
>
> In the "Add directory path" window that pops up,
>
> - enter C:\mingw\include\wx- as "Directory"
> - check "Add to all configurations" (this refers to Build, Release,    etc...)
> - select "OK"
> - navigate to "C/C++ General" -> Indexer

Comment: It works! Thanks! I see, you got right side http://stackoverflow.com/q/3166319/1035174